# Cakephp $this->Form->postLink Not working

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I using cakephp framework 2. to develop a Employee daily attends, in my application index page i have have 3 options edit , apply holiday, and deleted holiday. Two links, edit and apply working correctly but for delete i am using post link. When there is one delete button as required it did't pass parameter to delete function, but creating copy of same link mean two delete button then the last one pass parameter, i did'd now there is any thing wrong in my code. Here is my View code

```
<?php 

 $i=1; 
 foreach($holidays as $holiday):?>
  <tr >
     <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $holiday['Holiday']['title'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $holiday['Group']['title'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $holiday['Shift']['title'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $holiday['Holiday']['from_date'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $holiday['Holiday']['to_date'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-  pencil"></span> Edit',array('action'=>'edit', $holiday['Holiday']['id']),array('class'=>'btn btn-warning','escape'=>false)); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Apply',array('action'=>'applyholiday', $holiday['Holiday']['id']),array('class'=>'btn btn-success','escape'=>false)); ?>
                     <?php
                        echo $this->Form->postLink(
                            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete',
                            array('action' => 'delete', $holiday['Holiday']['id']),
                            array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?','escape'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-danger')
                        );
                    ?>



    </td>
  </tr> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>    
  <?php unset($holiday); ?>
```

Here is my HolidaysController code for delete function.

```
public function delete($id){
         if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
            debug($id);
            exit;
            if($this->Holiday->delete($id)){

                $this->Flash->success(__('Record Deleted Success.'));
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

First : **postLink Creates an HTML link, but access the URL using method POST** , [(see more information here)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)
means your method of request is post.

And Second:Your condition in delete function is:

```
if($this->request->is('get')){
  //
}
```

Means your request is never going to inside your function.
Hence just try using:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
  //
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use post instead of get in your controller.

```
 if(($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){
  //Code goes here
 }
```